# 500 error after creating htpasswd and edit htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I just edited the `.htaccess` file to include:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/path/to/public_html/
Require valid-user
```

I then created a `.htpasswd` file via the `htpasswd` command. I have enabled the module: `LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so` in the Apache configuration.

Now, when I load the page I get a 500 error and Apache log says:

> configuration error:  couldn't check user.  No user file?: /

Comment: What does your error_log say?

Comment: /path/to/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AuthUserFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 5):

The `AuthUserFile` command is provided by the `mod_authn_file` module.  Make sure your Apache configuration includes something along the lines of:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
```

This would need to go into the main server configuration, not in a `.htaccess` file.  If you don't have access to the main server configuration you'll need to contact your local administrator.

Comment: That allowed for for some progress.. I have edited my post to include the new apache error

Comment: If you're config really has `AuthUserFile /home/path/to/public_html/` you've got a problem, because that's not a path to a file.  The `AuthUserFile` directive specifies the path to an htpasswd-style file containing usernames and passwords.

Comment: No I have included the actual path to my directory I just didn't include it in the post

Comment: Right, it shouldn't be a path to a directory. It should be a path to a file.

Comment: You should also make sure that the webserver has read permissions on the AuthUserFile. Just a thought :)